# Relacionar tablas con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero relacionar dos tablas, y guardar los dos id en otra tabla para relacionarlos, por ejemplo:

Estoy logeado con un usuario, y creo un producto, como añado el id del usuario y el id del producto en una tabla adicional si aún no se ha creado el producto y no tengo su id? Sin utilizar el metodo de sumarle +1 al ultimo id del producto ya que puede dar conflicto si hay mas de un usuario creando productos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué quieres hacer, pero si quieres referenciar a un producto antes deberás crearlo para mantener la integridad. Creo que deberías añadir más información de que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente y como lo estas intentando.

Comment: Vale, si creo el producto antes, como cojo su id para hacer la relación tienda-producto?

Comment: Haz que las IDs sean autoincrementables en las tablas, asi no tendras que insertar la id, se insertara sola tras el ultimo registro existente.

Comment: No puedes usar una intermedia sin tener los valores, pero es fácil de corregir esto, no es mas que una relación N:M normal. Crea el Usuario, luego el Producto y finalmente en la intermedia mete los valores de la id de ambos (tienen que haber realizado el "->save()")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta corta no puedes hacer lo que dices, debes primero crear el producto, después de eso es sencillo relacionarlos, la opción más viable es crear primero la migración correspondiente, te recomiendo seguir las convenciones de `Laravel`.

---

Asumiendo que tus dos tablas sean `users` y `productos` en tu línea de comandos crea una migración `php artisan make:migration create_producto_user_table`.

En tu migración:

```
Schema::create('producto_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('producto_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('producto_id')->references('id')->on('productos')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['producto_id', 'user_id']);
});
```

Asegurate que en las migraciones tanto `users` como `productos` el `id` sea incrementable, si creas la migración por medio de un comando `artisan` ya aparecerá automáticamente, si no agrega al inicio de la migración `$table->increments('id');` debe quedar más o menos así:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    //Las demás tablas
...
Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    //Las demás tablas
...
```

En tus modelos:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
...
    public function productos()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
    }
```

//

```
class Producto extends Model
{
...
    public function usuarios()
        {
         return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
        }
```

En el `controller` de tu elección en el cual vayas a crear el producto y asociarlo al user:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Producto;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function ejemplo(Request $request)
    {
        $producto = new Producto;
        $producto->nombre = $request->nombre;
        ... #Y todos los datos recabados con tu form.
        $producto->save();

        //Al momento de pasar la función save() a la variable $producto 
        //se guardan los datos en la DB y te retorna el id
        //de esa forma puedes pasarle el id a la tabla intermedia

        //Asumo que el user que creo el producto será el actualmente logeado
        $user = Auth::user(); //De no ser así aquí haces el query para encontrar el user
        $user->productos()->attach($producto->id);
        //Aquí agregaste el id del producto 
        //y se asume el id del usuario para guardar 
       //ambos en la tabla intermedia

    }
}
```

Listo, ya tienes la relación.